# Converting 1080i5994 DNxHD HQ to 1080p

Tags: encoding, standards-converter, broadcast

I recorded some long format talks in 1080i5994 DNxHD via my atomos recorder. I do this all the time and never have any issues. I record in that format because thats what my switcher puts out and it always just works. This time though, I recorded some screens from the presenters laptop which look fine on the recording. The recordings are all 100gb or larger so I can't upload that directly to vimeo or youtube. So I edited them and rendered them them to h.264 10mb but the smaller text on the screen is now blocky and unreadable. Larger text is fine though. What's a better way to do this in the future and is there a way to convert these so that the smaller text is still sharp?

I'm using Adobe Media Encoder with the vimeo preset. I've tried a variety of different settings and can't seem to get better results on the smaller text.

Here is the captured image.
[image: Orginial Capture]

Here is the rerendered image quality. This is still a 6gb file for 1 hour.
[image: Rerendered Still]

Comment: Which encoder? Deinterlacer? Settings?

Comment: @ahackney can you share a frame grab of the output file that has the issue?

Comment: @MichaelLiebman Added images as requested.

Comment: That almost looks like a scan converter doing some poor down-sampling, except for it not being present on the source. It won't get you to a good size for uploading, but have you tried an MPEG2 to rule things out?